# Deserializing JSON with Jersey and MOXy into a List collection

Tags: java, json, jersey, moxy

I'm trying to take JSON objects and put them into a collection (I picked List). I've been able to unmarshal the JSON responses into single POJOs by creating BuiltCharacter with the appropriate getters and setters. For an array of JSON elements, I tried the following approaches:

```
List<BuiltCharacter> characters = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<BuiltCharacter>>(){});
```

and

```
List<BuiltCharacter> characters = client.target(uri).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(new GenericType<List<BuiltCharacter>>(){});
```

Using those approaches got me the following:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: BuiltCharacter cannot be cast to java.util.List

I originally used Character as the class name but was reminded that that is a reserved class name. Still, I can't figure out what's going on here!

Comment: How does the JSON, you're trying to deserialize, look like? Is it really an array?

Comment: @MichalGajdos, this is the example I'm using: http://census.soe.com/get/ps2:v2/character/?character_id=5428010618020694593,5428010618035589553

If I try to use a single POJO for this, both of my code examples above will actually successfully read both JSON elements into a single object. Thus, when I look for character.first_lower, it will return both "Dreadnaut" AND "Daddy". It's perplexing!

Comment: Would you care to share a bit more of the code? Maybe the whole method or even the REST resource class?

Comment: Hi, I have started this bounty. You can see an example here: http://krishantha.net/notes/restfull-services-in-java-with-jersey-part-3/ . What doesn't work is the method `public List<SalesType> getSalesType() {
        WebTarget target = client
                .target("http://localhost:8080/SalesMonitor/webapi/");
        List<SalesType> response = target.path("saletypes")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(new GenericType<List<SalesType>>(){});
        System.out.println(response);
        return response;
    }`, I get `SalesType cannot be cast to java.util.List`

Comment: @George please post as an answer (with a note of it being just reference; you can delete it later) (1) Your resource class (2) The SalesType class (3) Your dependencies. I cannot reproduce the problem. The JSON the OP linked to is a JSON object, which does not map to a List. It needs to be a JSON array.

Comment: I've tested with Jersey/MOXy 2.2 - 2.14 (got lazy to go up to 2.17) and it works fine, given a `List<SalesType>` is actually returned from the resource class

Answer (score 2):

**Answer in regards to bounty, but it seems to be the same problem from the original post**

Looking at [the link](http://krishantha.net/notes/restfull-services-in-java-with-jersey-part-3/) you provided, all the examples return `SalesType`, and not a `List<SalesType>`. You can't expect a `SalesType` to be converted to a `List<SalesType>`. If you are returning `SalesType` from your resource class, the exception provided.

Even from [the link](http://census.soe.com/get/ps2:v2/character/?character_id=5428010618020694593,5428010618035589553) for the original post, the JSON is coming in as JSON object. `List` doesn't map to a JSON object (`{}`), but instead a JSON array (`[]`).

If you want a list of `SalesType`, then simply return a list from the resource. Below is a complete example

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Test;

class SalesType {
    public String test;
}
public class MOXyTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Path("test")
    public static class TestResource {

        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response getSalesTypeList() {
            List<SalesType> list = new ArrayList<>();
            SalesType sales = new SalesType();
            sales.test = "test";
            list.add(sales);
            list.add(sales);
            return Response.ok(
                   new GenericEntity<List<SalesType>>(list){}).build();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(TestResource.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetSalesTypeList() {
        List<SalesType> list = target("test").request()
                .get(new GenericType<List<SalesType>>(){});
        for (SalesType sales: list) {
            System.out.println(sales.test);
        }
    }
}
```

These are the two dependencies I used (making use of [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html))

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Your problem can easily be reproduced by return the `sales` in the resource class from the example above. The current code above works, but just to see the error, if you replace the `GenericEntity` (which is a wrapper for generic types being returned in a `Response`), you will see the same error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.stackoverflow.jersey.test.SalesType
                              cannot be cast to java.util.List
```